# Unable to implement jQuery on shipping method selection : Magento2

Tags: magento2, shipping-methods

I want hide and show custom message on radio button selection of shipping method on checkout page , but jQuery is not working in that section due to knockoutjs.
Anyone have any idea for that how to implement custom jquery on shipping method selection?

here is my jquery code :

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    require(["jquery"], function($) {
        jQuery(document).ready(function(){
   jQuery('.radio').click(function() {
    alert("selected shipping");
   });

        });
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 require(["jquery"], function($) {
        $(document).ready(function(){
              $(document).on("click", '.radio', function () {
                  alert("selected shipping");
              });    
        });
    });
</script>
```

**Try this...!**

Comment: your most welcome...!